# How to categorize names in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query written below. there are the account names. they are giving me all database records. but i want the categories. for example if there are account name like 'salaries' then they should come under the salary title. if they are related to the 'expenses' then it should come under the expenses title. Please check out the below query

```
SELECT T1.[FormatCode], T1.[AcctCode], T1.[AcctName], T4.[Name] ,T2.[Name],
       T0.[DebLTotal], T0.[DebRLTotal], T3.[Debit], T3.[RefDate]
FROM OBGT T0
  INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
  INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
  INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account]
  INNER JOIN OASC T4 ON T1.[Project] = T4.[Code]
```

I want the categories according to the account code. for example if code is 51 then it is 'salaries' and all. Please expert help me.I am struggling with this thing for so long.

Comment: Couple of things 1..You need to create the tables in SQLFiddle and help us understand the schema. 2.. Provide us with a sample output that is required. Without these, there is not much that we can do to help you.

Comment: ok @Vasan i am giving you all things in short while.

Comment: @Vasan can you givr the link for sqlfiddle. i am new here. and tell me how can i give you all things that you required. please tell me.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com is a free websites that lets you create tables on the fly and save queries against multiple RDBMS, including SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T1.[FormatCode],  ( case when  T1.[AcctCode]=51 then 'salaries' when  T1.[AcctCode]=52 then  'dfds' end) as  AcctName, T4.[Name] ,T2.[Name],T0.[DebLTotal], T0.[DebRLTotal], T3.[Debit], T3.[RefDate] FROM 
OBGT T0 INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode]=T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account] INNER JOIN OASC T4 ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code]
```

Comment: i tried this way. its not working. i want account name should be 'salaries'. you are changing here accountcode then 'salaries' what ?

Comment: it is giving me null values for accountName

Comment: is their any record in your table with T1.[AcctCode]=51 ? or take a look at the join contraint, the fields may be not equal

Comment: yes. there is . this query giving me all acoount name null for every accountcode

Comment: `select ( case when  T1.[AcctCode]=51 then 'salaries' when  T1.[AcctCode]=52 then  'dfds' end) as  AcctName from OACT `  Does this query produce any result?

Comment: No, still getting NULL values for account name

Comment: `select ( case when  T1.[AcctCode]='51' then 'salaries' when  T1.[AcctCode]='52' then  'dfds' end) as  AcctName from OACT T1`   Check this please

Comment: I tried this thing on your previous comment. same result i am getting . NULL values for account names

Comment: but their is a slight difference in 2 queries

Comment: you have just added T1 . there is no difference otherwise